# Caching .com files on the filesystem in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route like "http://example.com/sites/example.com"
`get "/sites/:domainname", :to => 'controller#action', :constraints => { :domainname => /.*/ }`

It works until the cached page public/sites/example.com generated (instead of public/sites/example.com.html), at which time it asks the user to save a .com file. How would I make the cached page saved as, e.g. public/sites/example.com.html? Or possibly have a different workaround.

Comment: What does your controller action currently look like?

Comment: It has `caches_page :features, :show ` and `def show; render :layout => @layout` The caching mechanism things that .com is a format extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for, [`caches_page`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Pages/ClassMethods.html) automatically assumes the extension of the cache file should be the "extension" it finds when the path contains a period (`.`). This logic is actually in another method, `page_cache_file`:

```
      def page_cache_file(path, extension)
        name = (path.empty? || path == "/") ? "/index" : URI.parser.unescape(path.chomp('/'))
        unless (name.split('/').last || name).include? '.'
          name << (extension || self.page_cache_extension)
        end
        return name
      end
```

If needed, you could probably override this method to operate slightly differently within your controller, or else use the default ActionController::Base implementation. Here's a possible example:

```
  class MyController < ApplicationController
    class << self
      private

      # override the ActionController method
      def page_cache_file(path, extension)
        # use the default logic unless this is a /sites/:domainname request
        # (may need to tweak the regex)
        super unless path =~ %r{/sites/.*}

        # otherwise customize logic to always include the extension
        name = (path.empty? || path == "/") ? "/index" : URI.parser.unescape(path.chomp('/'))
        name << (extension || self.page_cache_extension)
        return name
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The current workaround is to force the html extension in routes:

`get "/sites/:domainname.html", :to => "sites#show", :as => :site, :constraints => { :domainname => /.*/ }`

this results in `public/sites/example.com.html` being saved in the cache.

Comment: Does that mean your URLs must be like `/sites/example.com.html` ?

Comment: Yes, the URLs have that siht in them now.

Comment: See my answer below for an alternate suggestion